# Error Code: 1072. Key column 'WORKDEPT' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, database

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT  (  
          DEPTNO int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
          DEPTNAME VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL ,   
          MGRNO CHAR(6) ,   
          ADMRDEPT CHAR(3) NOT NULL ,   
          LOCATION CHAR(16) ,  
          PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO),  
    FOREIGN KEY(WORKDEPT)  
    REFERENCES DEPARTMENT  
        (DEPTNO));
```

Getting this

> Error Code: 1072. Key column 'WORKDEPT' doesn't exist in table

i have tried adding column "WORKDEPT" but then i got error

> Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'WORKDEPT' and referenced column 'DEPTNO' in foreign key constraint 'department_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to add a foreign key to another table in which (1) the referenced column in that table doesn't exist, or (2) the referenced column in that table isn't a key, or (3) the referenced column in that table isn't the same type as the foreign key column in this table.  Please add complete `CREATE TABLE` statements for *both* relevant tables as a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It seems that you confuse what to what must refer on. Does `WORKDEPT` is a column in some another table?